# Connect url to controller class in spring mvc

Tags: javascript, html, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am using Thymeleaf and HTML for the view part. And spring 3. There is a list of radio button of which you should select only one. I am validating that using

```
                `<script th:inline="javascript">
                    /*<![CDATA[*/
                          function choose_report_kind (form_name) {
                              var form = document.forms[form_name];
                              var group = form.elements['report_kind'];

                              var report_kind;
                              for (var i = 0; i < group.length; i++) {
                                  if (group[i].checked == true) {
                                      report_kind = group[i].value;
                                  }
                              }

                              var url;
                              if (report_kind == "aos") {
                                  url = "/CustomReports?section=choose_organization";
                              }
                              else if (report_kind == 'aos_2007') {
                                  url = "/MarriottReporting1/CustomReports/2007?section=choose_organization";
                              }
                              else if (report_kind == 'aos_2008') {
                                  url = "2008/CustomReports?section=choose_organization";
                              }
                              else if (report_kind == '2009_pulse') {
                                  url = "pulse/2009/CustomReports?section=choose_organization";
                              }
                              else {
                                  alert("You must choose a type of report to run");
                                  return;
                              }
                              window.document.location.href = url;
                          }
                          /*]]>*/
                          </script>`
```

and I have to pass this URL to my controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/CustomReports/{year}?section=choose_organization", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView customReportsHome(@RequestParam("section") String section,@PathVariable("year") String year,HttpSession session, Map<String, Object> map){
    logger.debug("INSIDE CUSTOMREPORTHOME REQUEST PARAM");
    return new ModelAndView("CustomReports");
}
```

But I am not able to get anything, and I am getting error saying `CustomReport not found.`

Comment: your spring RequesMapping doesnot match the url pattern in the javascript.

Comment: Can you help me out how it should be as i am new to this?

Comment: Looking at the 4 url patterns that you have there.. i think this @RequestMapping makes more sense to me.. `@RequestMapping("/CustomReports/{section})` and then use `@RequestParam("year")` and `@PathVariable("section")` to fetch them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the RequesMapping doesnot match the url pattern in the javascript.

Looking at the 4 url patterns that you have there.. 
Try these changes...

Javascript:

```
if (report_kind == "aos") {
    url = "/CustomReports/choose_organization";
} else if (report_kind == 'aos_2007') {
    url = "/MarriottReporting1/CustomReports/choose_organization?year=2007";
} else if (report_kind == 'aos_2008') {
    url = "2008/CustomReports/choose_organization?year=2008";
} else if (report_kind == '2009_pulse') {
    url = "pulse/2009/CustomReports/choose_organization?year=2009";
}
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/CustomReports/{section}")
public ModelAndView customReportsHome(@PathVariable("section") String section,@RequestParam(value="year", required = false) String year,HttpSession session, Map<String, Object> map){
    logger.debug("INSIDE CUSTOMREPORTHOME REQUEST PARAM");
    return new ModelAndView("CustomReports");
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what the `Map<String, Object> map` will give you in the controller.. if spring cannot bind that then your controller method cannot be reached by the spring delegate.

Comment: Still i am getting the same error. Can you tell me how the controller is called from a "window.document.location.href = url;"?

Comment: you need to add context path to your url. for e.g., url needs to prefix something like `http://<server-host>:<server-port>/`.. so the fully qualified assignment would be something like this `window.document.location.href = "http://<server-host>:<server-port>//MarriottReporting1/CustomReports/choose_organization?year=2007";` check http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location to understand what that assignement does.

Comment: Thanks Sachin. I will try that out.